# localhost phpMyAdmin wont open because I deleted composer folder inside it

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, composer-php

I am new to php and usage of composer in php. I am using windows 10.

While trying to delete previous installation of composer I think I have mistakenly deleted the composer folder inside phpMyAdmin. Now I am getting the below error while trying to access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ :

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\autoload.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\autoload.php on line 5

was there supposed to be a composer folder inside phpMyAdmin by default? Did I delete something that was used by mysql?

How do I solve it?

Comment: Why not simply reinstall phpMyAdmin?

Comment: because I have tables and databases?

Comment: How is that related to phpMyAdmin? That's a tool that provides a GUI to a MySQL database, and reinstalling phpMyAdmin does not modify any data already stored in the database

Comment: I am using xampp. so have to uninstall the whole thing and reinstall it. Which i suppose will remove everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vendor` folder is required yes. If there's a `composer.json` file present in your `phpmyadmin` folder you can run `composer install` to fetch all dependencies into the `vendor` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go To xampp>phpMyAdmin first then run "composer install" on your git bash or any other terminal.I hope it will work